# Efficient Symmetric Matrix Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Is there a trick to quickly get the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix? I know one exists for circulant matrices, but I've searched online and can't find any reference to such a formula for symmetric.

Comment: There are better algorithms to diagonalize when symmetric, although I wouldn't call them "tricks" as they aren't "that" slick.

Comment: There's no quick way to get the exact values for the eigenvalues, but one common algorithm to get the approximate eigenvalues is [Jacobi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm).

Comment: The eigenvalues can be roots of non-solvable polynomial. So they cannot be computed explicitly, but only approximated.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This makes sense.